# Send alert message(data) from one login user session to another

Tags: django, django-templates, django-messages, django-notification

I have a use case where a user (manager) creates a task (1st view) and another logged in user (employee) can view the task created (2nd view). If the employee rejects the task clicking reject button, an alert should notify the manager. How do I achieve this functionality? Thanks for any guidance.

Comment: You will likely need some intermediary storage mechanism (a database, Redis store, etc.) to store this, as the `requests` module is specific to a given session (if I recall correctly). So, when the employee clicks reject, you store a record, and you scan for said records on the manager side.

Comment: Alright @JonahBishop Thanks